# Linking expressions to introduce advantages and disadvantages

Tags: expressions

In an argumentative text/essay what linking expressions can be used to introduce the pros and cons of the essay topic/object/theme, after a short introduction?

For example, if I'm writing an argumentative essay about some website, what linking expressions can be used to introduce its advantages and disadvantages?

Is the example below correct?

> However, as everything, X has its advantages and disadvantages.
> Being one of them[...]

Comment: To use *however* we need to know the preceding statement. This is because *however* introduces a contrasting topic. Otherwise, "As *with* everything, ..." or "As is usually the case, ..." could be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in this way. However you can improve this a lot better, this is just to give some idea.

X has both positive and negative aspects.

To begin with, .... (write some advantages)

Additionally, ..(write another point of advantages)

On the other hand,.. (write disadvantages and justify them)

Answer (score 0):

Based closely on your example sentence:

However, as with everything, X has it's advantages and disadvantages. One problem is that ...  On the other hand, an important advantage is ...

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in my comment, there are many different ways to present an argument.  The one most related to your example is something like:

> X website is one of the most popular in the world, with over two billion unique users.  However as with anything, it has its advantages and disadvantages.

Then go on to list some advantages

> First, it's a pretty blue color.  Second, it's free.  Third, etc. ...

Some expressions to change direction:

> The drawbacks include ...
>
> On the other hand, some drawbacks are ...
>
> That being said, some drawbacks are ...
>
> Although these (advantages) make it very attractive, some drawbacks include ...
>
> Still, X website has some notable drawbacks, which include ...

and many more.  After that, go on to list some of the disadvantages.

> For starters, your mother is on there with you.  Secondly, she posts dirty jokes every day.  Lastly, etc. ...